# What rules did Lucas have for the Expanded Universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, george-lucas

Back when he was in charge of *Star Wars*, Lucas had at least one rule that Expanded Universe authors had to follow, [Yoda's species and background could not be revealed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda's_species#cite_note-Unscripted-6).

Did Lucas have any other rules that EU authors and writers had to follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This interview](http://web.archive.org/web/20080118041727/http://www.totse.com/en/ego/science_fiction/tzi2.html) with Timothy Zahn, who wrote the first post-Jedi EU novels, mentions that they didn't want him to touch on the Clone Wars era since Lucas was planning to fill in those details himself in the prequels:

> The first book was pretty well organized before I started writing. We
>   added a couple of scenes and made some major revisions to the end of
>   it before it went to LucasArt. They looked at the outline and told me
>   a couple of things I couldn't do. They cut out my favorite character.
>   And originally, Joruus C'baoth was going to be a clone of Obi-wan
>   Kenobi, but they said no. They didn't want me to refer in detail to
>   the clone wars which took place before the movies began. I guess by
>   that time Lucas had decided he was going to go back and make the
>   prequel movies, and they didn't want me treading on his turf.

[This article](http://www.eucantina.net/archives/11661) also plausibly claims (though it doesn't give a source) that a lot of other prequel-era questions were off-limits:

> The novel and its sequels, Dark Force Rising and The Last Command, performed well beyond expectations, and the Expanded Universe was born.
>
> The novels, as acclaimed as they are, suffer from a fatal flaw—certain topics, such as the identity of Luke and Leia’s mother, the Clone Wars, and Anakin Skywalker’s fall to the dark side, were off limits, and they continued to be so until the prequel trilogy was released.

[This interview](http://www.bookloons.com/cgi-bin/Columns.asp?name=James%20Luceno&type=Interview) with EU author James Luceno in 2005 also mentions that Palpatine's history was off-limits (which later changed with the publication of Luceno's *Darth Plagueis*), as was Yoda's, as was the identity of the [Whills](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Journal_of_the_Whills):

> For the foreseeable future, some areas are going to remain off-limits. These include Yoda's species and backstory, details about Darth Sidious's apprenticeship, and information about the mysterious Whills.

Comment: Anything about Yoda's species, including the name or the existence of other members, was also banned by Lucas (with a few exceptions, like Yaddle). In fact, Lucasfilm did not approve the creation of [a Topps card depicting many of his species in one place](http://theswca.com/images-art/05.12-rheume.html).